# How to display child object fields in the VF page By querying through Parent object in SFDC

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I want to query child object through relationship from Parent object .And i need to pass those values to a VF page .How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can query child fields through a subquery like so:

```
select Id, Name,
        (select Id, Name from Child__r)
from   Parent
```

Store the results in a list of the parent objects:

```
list<Parent__c> liParents = [select Id, Name,
                                    (select Id, Name from Child__r)
                             from Parent];
```

Then you can then loop over the children in the page with something like this:

```
<apex:repeat var="p" value="{!liParents}">
    <apex:outputText value="{!p.Name}: "/>
    <ul>
        <apex:repeat var="c" value="{!p.Child__r}">
            <li><apex:outputText value="{!c.Name}"/></li>
        </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
</apex:repeat>
```